# What can I do to stop the mail I send from being classified as junk?

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP script which permit me to send an email with a PDF by a click on a button. The script works but i received the mail in a junk email . I want to know why ? And what can i do for receiving the mail normaly.

```
$mail_to = "brian.millot@live.fr"; //Destinataire  
$from_mail = $dataed['EDI_FROM']; //Expediteur  
$from_name = "Nom"; //Votre nom, ou nom du site  
$reply_to = $_POST['edi_from']; //Adresse de rÃ©ponse  
$subject = "Nouvelle commande";      
$file_name = $_POST['urlpdfvcmd'].".pdf";  
$path = "temp/";  
$typepiecejointe = filetype($path.$file_name);  
$data = chunk_split( base64_encode(file_get_contents($path.$file_name)) );  
//GÃ©nÃ©ration du sÃ©parateur  
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));  
$entete = "From: $from_mail \n";  
$entete .= "Reply-to: $from_mail \n";  
$entete .= "X-Priority: 1 \n";  
$entete .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";  
$entete .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\" \n";  
$entete .= " \n";  
$message  = "--$boundary \n";  
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\" \n";  
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit \n";  
$message .= "\n";  
$message .= "Bonjour ".$infcmd['CMD_CLT_LIV_NOM'].", <br /><br />
Veuillez trouver ci-joint le détail de votre commande no ".$infcmd['CMD_CODE'].". <br /> 
Cordialement. <br /><br />
".$sign['CST_SOC_NOMSOC']."<br />
".utf8_decode($sign['CST_SOC_ADRESSE_RUE1'])."<br />
".utf8_decode($sign['CST_SOC_ADRESSE_RUE2'])."<br />
".utf8_decode($sign['CST_SOC_ADRESSE_CP'])." - ".utf8_decode($sign['CST_SOC_ADRESSE_VILLE'])."<br />
Tel : ".$sign['CST_SOC_ADRESSE_TEL']."<br />
Fax : ".$sign['CST_SOC_ADRESSE_FAX']."";  
$message .= "\n";  
$message .= "--$boundary \n";  
$message .= "Content-Type: $typepiecejointe; name=\"$file_name\" \n";  
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \n";  
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\" \n";  
$message .= "\n";  
$message .= $data."\n";  
$message .= "\n";  
$message .= "--".$boundary."--";  

mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $entete);
```

Comment: There are many criteria that lead to your email being classified as junk. Some servers include their reasons in your received email headers. You might have to research that. Some criterie that I remember are: reverse lookup of sender domain doesnt match, not enough body, invalid headers

Comment: Blacklisting, whitelisting, greylisting. Take a look at those with regards to email servers. You can check by the IP or domain from which the email comes to see if it's blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad of reasons that email is considered junk or spam. I'm assuming the mail account your php server uses to send email is not the same as what you are saying is the "FROM" account in the actual email. This is pretty much a trigger in most email clients that you are sending spam and trying to make it look like it's from a reputable source.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strong reasion for your message to be marked as a junk. The mail server validates the ip address from source. "Every mail should be delivered by mail server only". If your message not passes through the mail server, then you mail will be thraeted as junk.

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding you right and you are saying the email was received but sent to the Junk Box, then I think the problem is with your email client, not the code.  The email client is what determines if a mail is junk or not, not the code that constructs the email.

Comment: Maybe it could be explained by the fact that i use the same email for "from" and "to" ? . I tested with the same email for both.

Comment: I wouldn't think that would be a problem - you can send emails to yourself with no issues.  You could try marking your email as "not junk" if your client supports it and then send again...

Comment: The email client determines if the email is junk based off of certain criteria such as the headers that you send with the email. Modifying your email to fit within the specified criteria could fix the problem. However, that would be a code problem not an email client problem.